# Как подключиться к таблице, которая находиться в БД Access с помощью Python

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, csv, ms-access

Всем привет! Необходимо подключиться к таблице БД Access, которая находится во вкладке таблиц сетевого доступа. [image: внешнее описание проблемы]

Я попробовала код,

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=путь к БД access;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from dbo.название таблицы')
   
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

но выходит данная ошибка

```
 ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC Microsoft Access] Ошибка синтаксиса в предложении FROM. (-3506) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Вы можете пожалуйста помочь решить проблему.

P.S.

Я попробовала просмотреть список таблиц, с помощью кода, и мне показываются только те таблицы, которые стоят отдельно(квадратики)(не в связке. Они на фотографии все стоят вначале до сетевых доступов(кружочков))

Проверка осуществилась с помощью данного кода.

```
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=путь к БД;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
for table_info in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
    print(table_info.table_name)
```

Результат выполнения

```
Table1
Table2
Table3
Table4
Table5
Table6
Table7
Table8
```

Comment: В структуре базы данных Access нет пространств имен, подобных Базам данных Postgresql, MS SQL или схемам Oracle. В секции `from` не нужно указывать `dbo` или что-то подобное. Просто пишите `select field1, field2, ... from tablename where conditions`

Comment: По поводу удаленных (внешних) таблиц. предположу, что `odbc` считывает данные только из локальных таблиц, осуществляя подключение к базе данных, как к источнику, не осуществляя запуск самого движка приложения Access. Сетевое же подключение осуществляется самим приложением.

Comment: 1) я и так и так пробовала. (2) я тоже это предполагала. Скорее всего так. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: 1) - пишите запросы в редакторе самого Access, проверяйте их работоспособоность, и только потом засовывайте из в код. В диалекте SQL Access много необычных деталей, которые надо учитывать. Он далеко не всегда синтаксически и семантически сопоставим с MS Sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите вот здесь `dbo.название` таблицы, префикс `dbo` и попробуйте выполнить такой запрос:

```
select * from Table1
```

Не путайте MS Access с SQL Server, синтаксис запросов отличается.